# onsen menu back-button returns to home.html page not last page

Tags: onsen-ui

Say I am on the third page, sNavigator.getPages() shows there are 3 pages on the list.
Opening the menu and choosing a menu item will empty sNavigator.getPages(), so the problem is that when I click back btn, I am supposed to return to the last page, but instead, I am returned to main page.
Why the pages are deleted, and how to keep them as a new pages?
My code:

```
<ons-sliding-menu main-page="home.html" menu-page="menu.html" side="left" var="menu" close-on-tap type="overlay" >
</ons-sliding-menu>

<script type="text/ons-template" id="menu.html">
  <ons-page modifier="menu-page">

  <div class="profile-pic-wrap">...
```

Comment: When you choose a menu item, is the function calling pushPage or is it doing resetToPage?

Comment: I think it's defined as resetToPage but this functionality is built in. I an not sure it works that way.

Comment: I am a bit confused then. You reference a navigator unless you are referring to the sliding menu which has a var of menu.  Since you are using v1 and if the call was coming from the sliding menu, I would assume the call would be to setMainPage. So, because you specifically state getPages, then I must assume you are actually referring to a navigator, which does not have a built in navigation component and you have to code that.  Thus, you should be able to find resetToPage - as that is the appropriate functionality and replace it with pushPage.  https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-navigator.html

Comment: https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-sliding-menu.html

Comment: This is my qestion: How to replace default behavior of the menu from "resettopage" INTO "pushPage"? Surely not by changing the core.

Comment: No change to core.  What I am saying is that somewhere in your code, there has to be a call to resetToPage.  Find that and change it to pushPage.  If you posted more of your code that is relevant, such as the JS, we could help out.